# Trigger or troubleshoot RunOnce

Tags: registry, windows-server-2012, .net-4.8

I'm working on tool which should schedule upgrade to .NET 4.8 silently through RunOnce registry feature so restart should happen on next restart.
Putting

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\myfolder\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe /q /forcerestart
```

On most systems like Win10, WinServer2016, etc. this works well but for WinServer2012 it often fails with no error or warning anywhere in event log.
Fail means that it creates temp folder like `C:\99ec22b874a8aa134731` as expected but then it remain empty and no installation process is running so it looks like it ended with error.

These are questions I think could help me bring more light but I failed to find answers:

1) Is there some other log than event log which could contain some output from RunOnce actions?

2) Is there any way how trigger RunOnce action manually as it would happen after restart?

Known things

- manual installation works properly
- UAC turned off, running under local administrator account

Comment: im looking for this same feature.  im using ansible, and running a script that unfortunately is  adding run once entrys.  i would like to use ansible to reboot system, and trigger the run once entrys, so that it can complete..